# An error occurred while listing api-gateway relations: Too Many Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have multiple Apigateway trigger a lambda. They can invoke lambda normally but when I want to see triggers of lambda after deployed by terraform or serverless framework, AWS often throws 429 error `An error occurred while listing api-gateway relations: Too Many Requests`. Can anyone shed any light please how can I fix it?
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMi9L.png)

Here is my config:

```
data "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = var.function_name
}

locals {
  resource_path = replace(var.resource_path, "/{.*}/", "*")
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = var.api_id
  resource_id             = var.resource_id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = data.aws_lambda_function.lambda.invoke_arn
}

# Create Lambda trigger to the method
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_api" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = var.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${var.api_arn}/*/${var.http_method}${local.resource_path}"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: We also need to see your Terraform or Serverless Framework config - the error is pretty self explanatory as somewhere somehow you are reaching the rate limit on listing resources - please add your IAC config to the Q

Comment: Thanks @ErmiyaEskandary I have updated the IAC config.